# How to synchronize data from local SQL Server database to remote SQL Server without using replication?

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronized

I have local SQL Server database and want to update data with remote sql database. i am using c# with asp.net. How to synchronize data from local SQL Server database to remotely hosted SQL Server database without the use of replication method?

I have used replication but did not get success. I think i have to try again. but i need alternative option of replication method.

Comment: When you reject the obvious tool for a job, it helps if you supply the *reasons* why you're rejecting the obvious tool. Because a) they may also apply to alternative suggestions that  wouldn't help you and b) they may be based on misconceptions.

Comment: So *why* do you need an alternative solution? What's wrong with replication, given that you managed it to work? Are there any transactions running while you synchronize, locally or remote?

Comment: Do you want to synchronize one table? multiple tables or the whole database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any specifics on your situation, however if the two SQL servers can communicate with each other directly, you can set up a linked server configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Once you have a linked server, you can write cross database queries against both databases using the [ServerName].[DatabaseName].[Owner].[Table] syntax to reference the remote tables. (This assumes the user you are logged in with can access both databases, or you set up the linked server with a passthrough authentication that allows updates to the remote database).

This is a bit of a stretch, since I don't know your configuration.